# Iterate resources in a puppet template

Tags: puppet

I am trying to manage my `/etc/hosts` file with puppet, but I don't like the internal 'host' type, I'd like to use my own template if possible.

I have therefore defined a 'host' resource:

```
    # Basic hosts configuration
    class hosts {

    # Host resource
    define host (
        $address,
        $names
    ) {

    }

    Network::Hosts::Host {
        before   => File['/etc/hosts']
    }

    # Configure hosts file
    file {
        "/etc/hosts":
        ensure   => present,
        checksum => md5,
        owner    => root,
        group    => root,
        mode     => 0644,
        content  => template("network/hosts.erb"),
    }
```

In other places, I define host resources:

```
network::hosts::host { 'puppet.test.lan':
    address => '192.168.56.101',
    names => 'puppet',
}
```

I would like to include the list of the defined hosts in my template, but I don't know how to iterate over the resources and their properties. I tried using string concatenation, but couldn't make it work and was not very elegant.

How can I iterate over all my defined hosts and include them from the template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use R.I.Pienaar's [puppet-concat](https://github.com/ripienaar/puppet-concat) module where you build a single file out of many smaller files or templates.

The define would then look something like this:

```
define host($address, $names) {
  concat::fragment{"hosts-$address":
    target  => "/etc/hosts",
    content => template("network/hosts_single.erb")
  }
}
```

The `hosts_single.erb` template would represent a single line in the file.  You'd probably also add a fragment for a header too and set `order => "01"` to ensure it's at the top of the generated file (10 is the default).

Comment: Thanks! I knew about puppet-concat. I can't still believe that Puppet doesn't make the data model available for templates: I'd like to some logical operations more than simply concatenating fragments.

Comment: Agree on jjmontes... this seems to be a pretty common requirement. I got hit by it often too, and I resort to dirty quick fixes. :-(

Answer (score 5):

I'd look at the [augeas library](http://augeas.net/) for managing the entries in your `/etc/hosts` file. It's a prerequisite for Puppet, so it's already installed. You may need to download an additional augeas package to gain access to the `augtool` command line utility. This is useful for testing before Puppet integration.

The hosts file entry an example listed on the main site:
http://augeas.net/tour.html

or

http://honglus.blogspot.com/2012/01/augeas-quick-start.html

I suppose you could also distribute a standard hosts file and just modify the line that needs to be unique per host...

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider augeas for this, but I'd still like to be able to use the technique I described for other kind of resources, so being able to iterate over them from templates would be great.

Comment: It gets the job done *sometimes*, but there are cases when augeas doesn't work with the file or that it's just not the right approach.